# Two side multi-select Jquery Plugin that supports group choosing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, selection

I am searching for a jquery multi-select plugin with two sides. The user can select one or more items and send them to the other side (chosen side).

However, the thing that I need the most is the ability to allow to select group of items.

I want the multiselect plugin to allow selecting either a group, or individual items within the group and transfer then to the other side (chosen).

Comment: [this](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) and [this](http://loudev.com/) seem like what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it is cool. Try it.

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

It also supports drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this plugin http://www.senamion.com/blog/jmultiselect2side.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I've found: [link](http://loudev.com/)